# How to accept params in Express POST call?

Tags: javascript, express, url, router

So I have an api where I have to pass car make, model, year in URL. I have express router post call to get the query params and set to object.

I need to be able to accept params in URL, so say
localhost:8080/cars/[not sure of this syntax but I need make:Audi?model:A4?year:2017]

I'm not sure of & and ? in above url, so please correct it.

```
router.post('/:make[not sure of this either but need to accept all params]),
function(req,res)
{
var make: req.query.make // here I should be able to get make of car and it should match query url
}
```

Please explain the actual URL I need to make post call and the URL for router.post

~SRJ

Comment: Could you please give a better example of the type of URLs you want to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call your URL like this and below should work:
localhost:8080/cars/Audi&A4&2017

```
router.post('/:make&:model&:year),
function(req,res)
{
const car = {
make: req.params.make,
model: req.params.model,
year: req.params.year
}
}
```

That will give you all properties in desired variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways you can use URL params in Express.js.

1. Using route parameters. `req.params` - with this method, you will need to specify the name of the param you are expecting to receive in the URL in your server route:

```
app.get('/cars/:make/:model/:year', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

and the URL will hold the values of each param in the order they appear in the route:

```
localhost:8080/cars/Audi/A4/2017
```

this will return:

```
{
    "make": "Audi",
    "model": "A4",
    "year": "2017"
}
```

you can access the specific URL param by simply adding the name of the param specified in your route like so: `res.send(req.params.make)`

2. Using query parameter. `req.query` - this will look closer to what you did. With this method, you don't need to specify the param name in your route, so your route will be:

```
app.get('/cars', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.query)
})
```

the URL will be like a key:value pair, starting with `?` to specify that this part of the URL is the beginning of the query params, following with `&` for each additional query param:

```
localhost:8080/cars?make=Audi&model=A4&year=2017
```

this will also return:

```
{
    "make": "Audi",
    "model": "A4",
    "year": "2017"
}
```

same as the route parameters method, you can also access a specific query param by adding it to the query param like so: `req.query.model`